# Is the response "It's 10 minutes walking" correct and natural?

Tags: grammar

- How far is the drugstore from here?
- It's 10 minutes walking.

I feel that I've read the second sentence (the response to the question) in a textbook. I'm asking this to make sure if it is a valid and a naturally spoken phrase or not. If not, why?

Comment: see also: "on foot/by foot" – ELU: ["By foot" vs. "on foot"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17943/by-foot-vs-on-foot)

Comment: **YES** it sounds perfectly natural. One way to look at it - there's a comma. It's ten minutes, walking.

Comment: To this brits ear, it feels more natural without the "ing" on the end.

Comment: Without a comma, it does not really sound too natural. It doesn't sound unusual per se, but no one says this. That said, everyone will understand what is meant by this

Answer (score 12):

After some discussion in the comments, I now think it’s possible to justify the sentence with or without the possessive, as short for either:

> It’s ten minutes [if you are] walking.

> It’s ten minutes’ [worth of] walking.

But neither is a common way to put it.  I’d be more likely to say (in American English)

> [It’s] a ten-minute walk.

> [It’s/It takes] ten minutes [to walk there].

> [It’s/It takes] ten minutes on foot.

Comment: I'd agree with the apostrophe if it were "It's a ten minutes' walk", but I'm not sure about "It's ten minutes' walking". As a parallel, it certainly wouldn't be "It's ten minutes' on foot".

Comment: There should be no apostrophe on “ten minutes walking" - you are simply saying: it’s ten minutes [spent] walking. To me (British English) using “walking” like this doesn’t sound natural, but maybe it‘s fine in US usage.
   There _is_ an apostrophe needed on the similar “It‘s ten minutes’ walk”. To help get that right, remember that it’s a walk **of** 10 minutes in duration, using “of” means that, grammatically, the walk “belongs” to the “ten minutes”, so you use the possessive.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Edited in my response to the great comments so far.

Comment: I agree very much that the implied [if you are] makes "walking" make sense in the sentence. "it's ten minutes" is the complete sentence with "walking" as a qualifier.

Comment: Resolved apostrophe "issue" aside, +1 for the three more likely alternatives.

Comment: I would say "ten minutes *by* foot".

Comment: @Acccumulation That works too. It’s also always *by* plane, train or automobile, although it can be either *by bike* or *on my bike*. Prepositions are one of the trickiest things to learn.

Comment: I don't find the original strange

Comment: In British English using the gerund sounds a little strange, unless you're comparing different modes of transport. The usual British expression would be "it's 10 minutes' walk"

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Using *a* in "a ten minutes' walk" would initially be parsed as incorrect for "a ten-minute walk" -- which is certainly idiomatic. Using *a* there is not idiomatic at all. ([Related Q&A on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/189180/18696))

Comment: You can't "justify" the sentence, it's idiomatic.

Comment: @Fattie no, the apostrophe is correct. It is a genitive expression equivalent to "a walk of 10 minutes" (this is shown by the lack of an article, something that would be required if this were "10 minutes" functioning as an adjective). The adjectival expression is "a 10 minute walk", with no /s/ and an indefinite article.

Comment: @Tristan I beg your pardon, I thought someone (ie, you) had added an apostrophe on the ***sentence in the OP question***  Thanks for pointing it out (I deleted my comment to avoid confusion, cheers)

Comment: no worries, it's easily done in text!

Answer (score 6):

It implies :- **it would take approximately 10 minutes to walk from here to the drugstore.**

***A 10-minute walk*** is a *formal way* of speaking the same.

Comment: Thank you. So, the response in question is not even spoken in causal conversation among the natives?

Comment: Yes, but not in a formal situation.

Comment: Formality has nothing to do with it. At least in British English, _ten minutes' walk from here_ would be the most idiomatic way to say it, but _walking_ isn't absolutely wrong.

Comment: What @KateBunting said. Or *a ten-minute walk from here*. The “a ten minute**s** walk” version is incorrect.

Comment: I agree that there's no question of formality here. Also not mentioning "10 minutes' walk" is a major disadvantage of this answer vs Davislor's

Comment: It’s certainly incorrect that “It’s a ten-minute walk” is more formal. If anything, I would say that “It’s ten minutes walking” is slightly more formal. There’s also no ‘approximate’ about it. Whether you say, “It’s ten minutes walking” or “It’s a ten-minute walk”, you’re saying that _it takes ten minutes to walk there_. If you wanted to be approximate, you would say, “It’s about ten minutes walking” or “It’s about a ten-minute walk”. @Tristan Davislor’s answer doesn’t mention ‘ten minutes’ walk’ either, only ‘ten minutes’ walking’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ah you're right, I saw the "ten minutes' walking" and the options with "walk" and just filled in the gap

Comment: @KateBunting: I would interpret "It's a ten-minute walk" somewhat differently from "It's ten minutes walking", with the former implying a judgment that other means of conveyance would not be worth considering even if they were available, but the latter implying an assumption that the listener intended to walk and allowing for the possibility that other means of conveyance might be faster if they happen to be available.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is all over the place.

Answer (score 5):

It's totally commonplace. In writing there'd be a comma.

{ Aside - just to be clear, I mean there'd be a comma in writing. There is no punctuation, whatsoever, in human utterances. }

You'd very often hear something like this ...

> It's ten minutes, walking. It's five minutes, driving.

Others have pointed out that other formulations ***are more common*** - but so what?

It's completely commonplace.

> I feel that I've read the [sentence] in a textbook.

Sure. FWIW it would have had a comma.

> I'm asking this to make sure if it is a valid

100% valid

> and a naturally spoken phrase or not

Yes, completely commonplace.

Comment: It does sound much more natural with the comma than without.

Comment: @Davislor  Sure.  Just TBC I (obviously!) meant "when it is written". There is no concept of punctuation in vocal utterances.

Comment: Right, although the comma would correspond to a pause in spoken English.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was a great one.